# Apache Solr - Boosting Results

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, solr

I'm new to using Apache Solr. Somehow managed to get it working but I've hit a wall. And that is boosting results.

Read a couple of articles saying this could be done by setting "pf" and "qf" parameters in the eDisMax parser. I've done that and managed to reach to some level.

But I need to sort the result that I've already boosted. There is a field that holds the values 1 or 0. And I need to sort the relevant search results in the descending order.

Is there a way that this could be done, keeping the relevancy as it is?

Appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 1):

Sorting feature in Solr doesn't intersect with eDisMax.

Take a look here - http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#sort, this is amazing guide how to sort by the field you want.

Use desc or asc, to get needed result

Comment: There is one problem though. When I do this, I mean use the "sort" parameter to sort results the results with the least score(s) comes up. Which means the results with the least relevancy comes on top of the search result.

Is there a way to save the world?

Comment: You could change the direction of sort by changing desc to asc

Comment: Oh come on Mysterion are you serious! :D

Comment: Does it help or not? Sorry, I'm not understanding your joke.